# Setting focus() on autocomplete textbox

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I am trying to set the cursor on the textbox that has been set to a kendoAutoComplete, but the cursor does not show.

Using Kendo's [AutoComplete basic demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/index.html) I am running the following code in the Chrome Developer console, but the cursor is not showing.

```
$('#countries').focus()
```

When the code is run, I do see that the span around the input box does get the 'k-state-focused' class which changes the border color to gray, but that's all it does.

From what I can tell, the 'k-state-focused' css class doesn't hide the cursor. So not sure if Kendo is somehow intercepting the focus in JavaScript and not setting it, or because the textbox has a span around it, the focus is being hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `$('#countries').focus()` do `$('#countries').data("kendoAutoComplete").focus()`.

Due to Kendo UI decorations around HTML elements you should use AutoComplete [`focus`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/autocomplete#methods-focus).

Comment: Thank you that works. I had always figured that data-attributes were only used for simple text values. Didn't realize you could store objects as well.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer didn't work for me. It could be because I'm using UI for ASP.NET Core, but this solution did work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#myInputId").focus();
    });
});
```

This is the explanation from Telerik - "The AutoComplete widget is designed to persist the focus of the input when popup element is clicked. The select is raised between of the open->click->close chain and that is why we will need to use setTimeout function to focus other input."

Comment: Can confirm this works and the accepted answer does not.